# Firestore security rules get field/id of reference

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have  two collections - tenancies and users.

A tenancy doc has a field called "landlordID" and is of type REFERENCE (not String).

Now in my Firestore Security Rules I want to allow a tenancy to be updated ONLY IF the landlordID field of that tenancy matches with the uid of the user making the request, namely `request.auth.uid`.

Read it as " allow a tenancy document to be updated if the user making the user is authenticated, hence request.auth.uid != null, and the landlordID field's ID should be equal to that of the request.auth.uid.

Hence the code should me something like this:

```
    service cloud.firestore {

      match /databases/{database}/documents {

        match /tenancies/{tenancyID}{

            allow update: if request.auth.uid != null && 
                        request.auth.uid == get(resource.data.landlordID).id
    }

}
```

I have also tried `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(resource.data.landlordID)).data.id`

Supporting screenshot of my database

[image]

This should be very simple but  get() simply does not work. [Firebase Docs, scroll to "Access other documents"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions) was not helpful at all for my situation and I am not sure how to get it working.

It would be a shame if references can't be used like this as they are just like any other field of a document.

Comment: Are you showing the actual rules that aren't working the way you expect?  If not, please edit the question to show exactly what you're doing.  As show, I'd expect them not to compile because there is no `nill`.  Did you mean `null`?

Comment: This is just a typo, on Security rulls it is "null". And yes I am showing a standalone rule that fails a simulation request that is supposed to go through.

Read it as " allow a tenancy document to be updated if the user making the user is authenticated, hence `request.auth.uid != null`, and the landlordID field's ID should be equal to that of the request.auth.uid.

Comment: Your get() is definitely not correct.  You need to pass a full document specifier to it, as you might see in the documentation.

Comment: See the second answer and my response. I have tried various versions of get with full paths etc including the version in the second answer, and it did not work. The second answer also indicates that it might not be possible to use references like this, which is a shocker to me.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a function I made that works for me. I guess you have a user collection with users having the same `id` as their `auth.uid`

```
    function isUserRef(field) {
      return field in resource.data
        && resource.data[field] == /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)
    }
```

Adjusting to your use case you'd call the function so: `isUserRef('landlordID')` although the ID at the end of it is  a bit misleading as this field is in fact a reference.

Comment: For others that need to get the id from a reference type field you will need to fetch the document first:
`get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(request.resource.data['owner'].path)).id == request.auth.uid`
Here owner is a reference of an user.

Answer (score 4):

I see a couple of issues here. A first problem is that the get() function expects a fully specified ducument path, something like:

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(resource.data.landlordID)).data.id
```

A second problem is that you are trying to use the reference type in your rules, I do not think that is possible unfortunately.

The reference type in Firestore is not very helpfull (yet), I think you should store the landlordID as a string, then you can simply do something like:

```
service cloud.firestore {

      match /databases/{database}/documents {

        match /tenancies/{tenancyID}{

            allow update: if request.auth.uid != resource.data.landlordID;

    }

}
```

Comment: I know this and and have tried multiple versions of what I put in get(), including constructing paths with path() etc. 

This is a shame as it make zero sense for it not to be helpful. A reference is just like any type and my apps logic is built around it not being a string field. Hard to see what is the point of having a type reference when you can't use in security rules.

Comment: I agree, it would be nice if the reference type was more useful.  I think I have read that the only use case for the reference type at the moment is that you can click on it in the Firestore console to get to the related document.

Comment: I just thought putting a "string" representing a reference to another document/subcollection in another collection should be done with the Reference type, I believe this is logical otherwise there is no point of it at all.  To conclude, in this situation there is no workaround apart from making landlordID into a String in my "schema" ?

Comment: Yes, I think that is the workaround you will have to go with. I have been using Firestore a lot, and I am always using strings to create relations between documents.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue I needed an answer for. See [this Google-thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/QPHV3JpQR7M/lgeWnGhHBwAJ) with the answer from someone from google. To quote it:

> You can get an id out of a path using the "index" operator:
>
> `some_document_ref` should look like `/databases/(default)/documents/foo/bar`
>
> which has 5 segments: `["databases", "(default)", ...]`
>
> `some_document_ref[4]` should be "bar"
>     allow create: if request.resource.data.some_document_ref[4] == "bar";
>
> You can also use the normal `get` and `exists` functions on them.
>
> A few difficult aspects of this that you may run into:
>
> - There's no way to retrieve the number of segments in a path at the moment (we're adding this soon), so you'll need to know some information about the reference ahead of time
> - There's not great support for writing references using the simulator in the Firebase Console. I used the Firestore emulator to test out this behavior (gist1, gist2)

Answer (score 2):

might be too late, but I was able to piece together (despite a lack of docs) that a document reference is just a path, and complete path can be created with

`/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)`

Then I have an array/list in firestore of references, called `reads` that I can grab with:

`get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)/userinfo/granted_users).data.reads`

Leaving me able to create a bool, and a rule with:

`/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid) in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)/userinfo/granted_users).data.reads`

obviously your data structure will vary, but knowing the ref is a path is the important part here.

Answer (score 1):

I had to experiment a little to get this working. Here the function that worked for me

```js
function isUserRef(database, userId) {
  return 'user' in resource.data
    && resource.data.user == /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId);
}
```

And I call it like:

```
match /answers/{answer} {
   allow read:
        if isUserRef(database, request.auth.uid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by some other answers, a reference has a `path` property that is just a string that will look something like `users/randomuserid123`. You can split that into an array and match it against the user making the update request.

```
...

match /tenancies/{tenancyID}{

 allow update: if request.auth.uid != null && 
   resource.data.landlordID.path.split('/') == ['users', request.auth.uid]
 }

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Also had a trouble handling this problem, but in my case I needed to allow the user to add a message into a chat only if they're the owner of that chat room. There are 2 "tables" - `chats` and `chat_messages`, and `chat_messages` relate to a specific chat through `chatId` field. `chats` objects have `ownerId` field.
The rule I've used goes like this:

```
    // Allow adding messages into a chat if the user is an owner of the chat room
    match /chat_messages/{itemId} {
      function isOwner() {
          return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chats/$(request.resource.data.chatId)).data.ownerId == request.auth.uid;
      }
      
      allow read: if true;
      allow create: if isOwner();
    }
```